# Is there a way to extract page properties from a PDF using iText?

Tags: c#, pdf, properties, itext

We are researching an issue that we are having with Adobe DC.  In some documents when we use the Scan & OCR/Enhance action, pages are rotated.  Through testing we have determined that it will always be the same pages that get rotated in a single document.  For example, we have pre-enhanced file 620449.pdf and all pages are in the correct orientation. After the Enhance action, 5 pages are rotated (all counterclockwise with varying degrees).  I tested by extracting the 5 pages that will be rotated plus 5 other pages from the pre-enhanced 620449 document into its own pdf (pages_from_620449.pdf).  We ran the enhance action and the same 5 pages rotated.  Our assumption is that there is some property in those specific pages that the Enhance action interprets as a rotation command.

Can I use C# and iText to extract all the properties from a single page so I can compare the values between “good” pages and “bad” pages?  If so, any pointers on what methods to use (I am fairly new to both C# and iText).

Thanks Rick

Comment: Can you post a sample document and indicate what pages are rotated and what not? The original document, not the one processed by Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

iText provides you with an open source tool to look into the heart of your PDF's, named RUPS ([information link](https://itextpdf.com/products/rups))